# Superset BigQuery Issue1011 (Unexpected param: (2022)) when charts executes query containing IN operator

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-superset, pybigquery

I have been using Superset for the past 2 months and have not experienced this issue before. I have created a number of charts and dashboards that have been functioning as expected for the past 2 months. All my charts pull from BigQuery

The base chart works fine, but as soon as I select a filter value, from a multi-select filter, I get the below error:

```
Unexpected param: (2022)
This may be triggered by: 
Issue 1011 - Superset encountered an unexpected error.
```

In SQL lab when I run the same expected query with the filter condition, it works, but when the chart runs the query, I get the 1011 issue

Chart Error with filter
[image: Chart Error with filter]

Chart Working without filter
[image: Chart Working without filter]

When I run this query in SQL Lab it works

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT `School`) AS `COUNT_DISTINCT_School__08531`
FROM `school_dw`.`vSchoolListFlat`
WHERE Period IN (2022);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had exactly the same problem. Try to install
`sqlalchemy-bigquery==1.4.0` library instead of `pybigquery==0.10.2`.

Comment: But how to install this library?